# Mysqli_Query -> INSERT INTO Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$bzSendMail = mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO messages_inbox (from, towho, subject, text, rcvdat) VALUES ('$MyID', '$SenderID', '$subject', '$text' ,'$sentat')");
```

I'm trying to make this query works, but it keeps showing me the following error!

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, towho, subject, text, rcvdat) VALUES ('1', '2', 'd', 'd' ,'2014-09-07 17:0' at line 1`

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `from` is a keyword and got to be escaped with backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using

> FROM

as a column name in your table. You can use '' to specify the column name  but it is always better not to use that kind of names as  your column names.

```
$bzSendMail = mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO messages_inbox (`from`, `towho`, `subject`, `text`, `rcvdat`) VALUES ('$MyID', '$SenderID', '$subject', '$text' ,'$sentat')");
```

Answer (score 0):

`From` is a key word in Mysql use backward quotes to skip this as follows

```
$bzSendMail = mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO messages_inbox (`from`, `towho`, `subject`, `text`, `rcvdat`) VALUES ('$MyID', '$SenderID', '$subject', '$text' ,'$sentat')");
```

Answer (score 0):

`from` is a reserved word in sql. Make backticks around it.